# React js - fetch API - TypeError: this.state.countryJson.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

How to read this type json format in reacts js
I'm trying to get fetch data  from http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees here and showing it to my page using react.js but i have an error TypeError: this.state.countryJson.map is not a function

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      countryJson: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
    .then(response =>{
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(countryJson=>{
        this.setState({countryJson});
        console.log(countryJson);
    });
  }
    render() {
       return(
         <div>
           {this.state.countryJson.map( (item, index)=>
              <p>{item}</p>
            )}
         </div>
       )
    }
  }
  export default App;
```

Comment: It's an object. What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: Please check this on how to ask good question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello! Is this some data that you have obtained through fetch request? OR is this what you want to obtain through fetch request but you don't know how? please be more specific about what you want and what is exactly your problem with so that I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an axios.get response? if yes just use response.data which is an array in your case

Answer (score 0):

You store in state the entire JSON response object, so in order to (presumably) read the array you need to access it via normal JS object dot notation. The JSON has two properties, `success` and `data`. `data` is an array.

```
this.state.countryJson.data.map((item, index) => (
  <p>{item}</p>
))
```

But the data is an array of objects, which aren't valid react children, so you'll likely need to map each property as well.

The other option, OFC, is to pick out and only store in state what you want/need, like just the data array.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(({ data }) => { // destructure from JSON response
      this.setState({ countryJson: data });
      console.log(data);
    });
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      {this.state.countryJson.map((item, index) => (
        <p>{item}</p>
      ))}{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```